# Filtering rows of FooTable

Tags: jquery, filtering, footable

I've first looked for similar questions, but with no successful answer. Here comes my problem:

[FooTable Filtering](http://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/examples/component/filtering.html)

How can I implement an example like this with the filtering example (Search text-box, lens and dopdown list with checkboxes corresponding to the table columns included)?

I mean, what kind of jquery I have to execute for reproducing the same behaviour as in the example? I exactly need the same behaviour, with the possibility to exclude the checked table columns from filtering the word written in Search text-box.

Comment: Please read the help section on how to ask questions. What have you tried? You try and need help, we're happy to help but not write the code for you.

Comment: I looked for sample code in GitHub concerning the specific filtering example they have displayed, but without success, I wasn't even able to find similar code from which to start. So, you are right, I haven't tried, but I do not really know where to start. You are right again, no write code for me, anyway I asked in case someone already dealt with the same problem, and found a starting point at least. Sorry, I wasted your time.